# new Contribution triggers send invoice

Tags: contributions, invoice, automation

Our Drupal web form is connected to CiviCRM and creates a new contribution. I want to automatically trigger civi to send an invoice based upon the new contribution as soon as it has been created. The contribution has the status "Pending". The invoice should be attached (as a PDF) to the email sending the invoice. I know how to do this manually.  How can I configure Civi to do it automatically?

I looked at CiviRules but could not construct a condition that worked.
Also looked at Schedule Reminders

What am I missing?

Using Drupal 8 / CiviCRM 5.45.3

This is not about sending a receipt or a thank you. I know how to configure them for automatic sending.

Comment: What do you mean by invoice? You could send a PDF, so question is what content/tokens do you need in an invoice?

Comment: When I view any Contribution, I can click on Download Invoice or Email invoice. That is the invoice That I am referring to. The content of the invoice is correct. It can be sent as a pdf. Also good. I can manually send incoices to the reclipient. I want to trigger the sending of the invoice to a person when a contribution is created and is in the pending status.  The goal is to automatically provide the person with a copy of their invoce which is based upon the data in the respective contribution.

Comment: Another idea, it would suffice to automaticlly send them ann email with a link to their online paymant dashboard which shows them a list of paid and pending invoices. I could use a sxcheduled reminder, if I kmew how to automatically create that link to theri payment dashboaard, sort of like a token.  Is that possible?

Comment: sorry, I am a few versions behind, so I cannot see the URL you are thinking of. But I imagine you could compose that URL with tokens..? Could you paste an example of such an URL?

Comment: worth checking if you can send a link to /civicrm/user with cid and checksum - i thought it worked but haven't tested recently

Comment: but not sure why this isn't just working out of the box - if you have webform_civicrm then an email should be able to go just based on the civicrm settings on the webform i believe

Answer (score 1):

If you install the PDF API extension (on an installation where CiviRules is installed) you will get the possibility to use the Send PDF action in CiviRules. You can then create an invoice template and use that?

Answer (score 0):

The CiviRule action to create an invoice doesn't exist, it would need to exist before this was possible.

Comment: Is there any other way to automatically trigger an invoice being sent based upon teh status of a contribution. Such as:  
- contribution created and is pending
- contribution status changed from pending to completed (so that receivere can see the invoice with itemized details [a list of participants, events, and fee for each event] and balance due of $0.)

Comment: You're itemizing triggers - but the issue isn't one of triggers, it's one of actions.  There isn't an action to send an invoice.